# Using switchMap with Promises

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable

I am learning Angular2, following the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial on Angular.io.  Near the end of the tutorial, we set up routing to a detail page and pass a parameter indicating the hero to displace.  This is handled using the params Observable in ActivatedRoute.  We use switchMap to redirect from the params Observable to a Promise to return the data we actually want based on the parameter.

The syntax used in the tutorial is concise, so I tried to break it out into building blocks to get a better understanding of what is going on.  Specifically, I have tried to replace **right arrow notation** with an actual function, that I think is identical.  But my modification does not work.

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
        //.switchMap(this.getHero)
        .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
    }

    getHero(params: Params) : Promise<Hero> {
        return this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']);
    }
```

What confuses me is why using the line that is currently commented out instead of the line above it, I get an error: `"Cannot read property 'getHero' of undefined."`  The two versions of code look identical to me.

Comment: One would be a method, the other an arrow function with bound `this`. Are you sure it's erroring on the `.getHero`, not the `.heroService` inside the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fat-arrow function preserves the context of execution, allowing the `this` "variable" to be the same as in the parent scope. If you use `.switchMap(this.getHero)` then `this` will point to something else, not the component.

```
getHero(params: Params) : Promise<Hero> {
    // "this" is not what you expect here
    return this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']);
}
```

So `this.heroService` is undefined here.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to `bind` your getHero function.

```
.switchMap(this.getHero.bind(this))
```

Otherwise your change is identical. Using bind like this allows you to pass `getHero` as a standalone function to switchMap without losing what `this` means to it.

You can experiment with it:

```
'use strict';
const foo = { 
  bar: 'baz',
  getBar: function() {
    return this.bar;
  }
};

foo.getBar();
// => 'baz'

const myGetBar = foo.getBar;
myGetBar();
// => TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined

const boundGetBar = foo.getBar.bind(foo);
boundGetBar();
// => 'baz'

const otherObj = { bar: 'hi' };
const otherBoundGetBar = foo.getBar.bind(otherObj);
otherboundGetBar();
// => 'hi'

otherObj.getBar = myGetBar;
otherObj.getBar();
// => 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `this.getHero` like in your snippet because

1. it's `undefined` (the service returns `Observable` that you have to `subscribe` before using its data)
2. it's not a property (doesn't have `get` modifyer).